# C++ Read Information from Image

Tags: c++, image, binary

I have to read some information from an image. When I drag the .tif image into Visual C++ 2006, it shows up like this:
[image]
 I am trying to read in the min and max values that are specified on the right hand side of time image (highlighted in yellow). How can I do this? When reading from files, I usually do something like this:

```
ifstream fileStream(file_name); 
string contents;
while(fileStream >> contents) //do something
fileStream.close();
```

However, when I try this approach with the given image and try couting contents as soon as information is read in, all that is printed out is:

```
contains = MM 
contains =
contains =
```

Clearly, it's not working. It only reads in information once, and stops reading after 3 iterations.

So, how can I go about getting the max and min values from the image?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Do not open a binary file as a text file.

Comment: Also, what are the "max and min values" of an image?

Comment: You need to start by converting the image to .bmp or some other format that reflects the vales of individual pixels. Familiarize yourself with image file formats... and recognize the difference between TEXT and BINARY files.

Comment: Probably (and cheaper) to get a printout and type the numbers in.

Answer (score 1):

Your example code is appropriate for reading text files, but your TIFF file is (mostly) binary.  So the first thing you have to do is open the file in binary mode.

```
std::ifstream fileStream(file_name, std::ios::binary);
```

The `<<`-style extractors are good for formatted text but not really appropriate for binary files.

You'll need to know about the file format to figure out where in the file to find the values you're after.  I don't know detail about TIFF, so you'll have to find a reference.  It will probably involve reading in a header (e.g., `fileStream.read(buffer, size)`), looking up an offset in the header, moving to that location in the file (e.g., `filestream.seekg(offset, ios::beg)`), and then interpreting the bytes at that location.

Here's a [decent tutorial on C++ file handling](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/).  Make sure you read the section called **Binary Files**.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `fscanf()`.

```
#include <cstdio>

FILE * file = fopen("filename.tiff","r");

char c;
fscanf(file,"%c",&c);
```

That will read a single byte from the file. By repeatedly calling `fscanf()` in this way, you can read the file, looking for the bytes 'm', 'i' and 'n' in the case of min. Once you have found this, you can then use

```
int num;
fscanf(file,"%d",&num);
```

to read the next occurrence of a *textual* number (a numerical value written in ASCII or other encoding as opposed to binary.

A full reference on the functionality of fscanf [can be found here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/).

Comment: Someone down voted your question, but didn't have the courtesy to leave a comment.  *tiff* files are generally binary, so while your `fscanf()` advice is correct for a *text* file, it doesn't work well for an image.  I believe the down vote was because you missed the larger issue.